# R build package with data

Tags: r

I'm building a package which need some data I created (.csv file), and I would like to know how can I use these files automaticaly when the package is loaded ? And in the code, to select one ?

My call for these files in my base function is :

```
df1<-read.csv("ngram1.csv",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
df2<-read.csv("ngram2.csv",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
df3<-read.csv("ngram3.csv",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
df4<-read.csv("ngram4.csv",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Check the [`use_data`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.5/topics/use_data) function from `devtools`.

Comment: That's the man-page, and it's a good tool. A \walk-through can be found in Hadley's [*"R Packages"*](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) book